# Pull out the common denominator of fractions

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, factorization

I have this code:

```
K[Q_, n_Integer] := 
 Module[{z, x}, 
  SymmetricReduction[
    SeriesCoefficient[
     Product[ComposeSeries[Series[Q[z], {z, 0, n}], 
       Series[x[i] z, {z, 0, n}]], {i, 1, n}], n], 
    Table[x[i], {i, 1, n}], Table[Subscript[c, i], {i, 1, n}]][[1]]]


poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, 4] /. c -> p;
primeFactorForm[n_] := 
  If[Length@# == 1, First@#, CenterDot @@ #] &[
   Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n]];
gcd = GCD @@ List @@ poly /. Rational[n_, d_]*c_ :> d;


For[i = 0, i < 8, i++, 
  poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, i] /. c -> p;  
  Print[Subscript[L, i], " = ", 
   1/primeFactorForm[gcd]* Plus @@ List @@ Distribute[gcd*poly] /. 
    Times[Rational[n_, d_], e__] :> 
     primeFactorForm[n]/ primeFactorForm[d]*e]] // Expand
```

It outputs polynomials in different variables, factorizing everything and calculating the common denominator so it can be pulled out. I have some problems with formatting (I need this for a paper so it should look good). When the polynomial has many terms, the common denominator is out to the left and the rest is in a round bracket to the right (something like $\frac{1}{23}(2p_1+\frac{5p_2}{2})$, but with many more terms). But when there are just a few terms in the polynomial the output looks like this: $\frac{2p_1+\frac{5p_2}{2}}{23}$, which is quite ugly for a paper. Can someone tell me how to enforce it to use brackets all the time? Thank you!

Comment: You should provide enough code and data to produce a minimal **working** example. Have you tried using `Simplify` or `Factor`?

Comment: @BobHanlon I added a working example. I tried using these, but maybe I didn't added them in the right place...

Comment: Perhaps, `For[i = 0, i < 8, i++, 
 poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, i] /. c -> p;
 Print[Subscript[L, i], 
  " = ", ((1/gcd*Plus @@ List @@ Distribute[gcd*poly]) // 
     Together) /. 
   Times[Rational[n_, d_], e__] :> n/primeFactorForm[d]*e]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
         For[i = 0, i < 8, i++, poly = K[Sqrt[#]/Tanh[Sqrt[#]] &, i] /. c -> 
           p;
           Print[Subscript[L, i], 
        " = ", ((1/gcd*Plus @@ List @@ Extract[(gcd*poly)]) // Together) // 
          FactorTerms /. 
           Times[Rational[n_, d_], e__] :> n/primeFactorForm[d]*e]]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Yes, But right now his 70% problem has been solved.